# pipenv --system option for docker. What is the suggested way to get all the python packages in docker

Tags: python, django, docker, pipenv

I use `pipenv` for my `django` app.

```
$ mkdir djangoapp && cd djangoapp
$ pipenv install django==2.1
$ pipenv shell
(djangoapp) $ django-admin startproject example_project .
(djangoapp) $ python manage.py runserver
```

Now i am shifting to docker environment.

As per my understanding `pipenv` only installs packages inside a `virtualenv`

You don't need a virtual env inside a container, docket container IS a virtual environment in itself.

Later after going through many Dockerfile 's i found `--system` option to install in the system.

For example the following i found:

https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/

```
COPY ./Pipfile /usr/src/app/Pipfile
RUN pipenv install --skip-lock --system --dev
```

https://hub.docker.com/r/kennethreitz/pipenv/dockerfile

```
# -- Install dependencies:
ONBUILD RUN set -ex && pipenv install --deploy --system
```

https://wsvincent.com/beginners-guide-to-docker/

```
# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Copy Pipfile
COPY Pipfile /code

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system
```

So `--system` is only sufficient or `--deploy --system` is better way. And `--skip-lock --system --dev` which is different again.

So can some one guide how to get my environment back in my Docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical Docker deployment would involve having a `requirements.txt` (it's a [file where you can store your pip dependencies, including Django itself](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html)) file and then in your `Dockerfile` you do something like:

```
FROM python:3.7  # or whatever version you need
ADD requirements.txt /code/
WORKDIR /code
# install your Python dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# run Django
CMD [ "python", "./manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

You don't need `pipenv` here at all since you no longer have a virtual environment as you say.

Even better you can configure a lot of that stuff in a `docker-compose.yml` file and then use `docker-compose` to run and manage your services, not just Django.

Docker [have a very good tutorial on dockerising Django](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) with it. And if you're unsure what's going on in the `Dockerfile` itself, [check the manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

Comment: So i use pipenv for my development in my host and use `pipenv lock -r requirements.txt` and then install using `pip -r requirements.txt` in the docker

Comment: Right, yes, you can carry on managing your dependencies using `pipenv`, what's important is that you have a `requirements.txt` file that you can use to set up the Docker environment with.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that there is no need for pipenv in Dockerfile but i just want to also understand the pipenv side of using it

Comment: `pipenv` is an environment and package manager in one, for simple use cases it's probably more than enough. Docker is helpful if you have multiple services running together (e.g. a separate database server, caching, logs) that interact with each other. If all you have is a self-contained Django application, not sure you need to go down the Docker route.

Comment: I understand all that. As i told you i will be using docker for micro services only. But this question is mainly about the usage of pipenv related. I am not using pipenv in docker to create a virtual env. Thats why they use --system option. But i observed some use --deploy and also --skip-lock . That why i was confused

Comment: If you always do `--skip-lock` you're negating the benefits of `pipenv` which is to lock down dependencies. `--dev` is for installing dependencies that are only needed in development. My suggestion is to create a `requirements.txt` file and list all your normal project dependencies there and then a separate file called `requirements_dev.txt` for all your dev dependencies. Then you can just do `pipenv install --system -r requirements.txt` for your main file and `pipenv install --system --dev -r requirements_dev.txt` for your dev dependencies. That should be it

Comment: not sure about your use case, --deploy fails the build instead of updating the lockfile, which is useful if you want to manually manage the Pipfile.lock file (I think)

Comment: This is bad advice. The lock file is supposed to replace requirements.txt. That's why you should use --deploy to avoid updating the lock file during the docker build. Also, one should still use virtual-env inside the docker as some of the docker tools use python and the system-wide should be kept untouch.
The whole purpose of pipenv is to reduce all the work of managing deployment and development to two files, not to add more manual steps to it.

Comment: Agree with @anishtain4, pip does not allow for deterministic builds, pipen does thanks to the lock file.

Answer (score 0):

In either a docker image, a CI pipeline, a production server or even in your development workstation: you should always include the `--deploy` flag in your installs unless you want to potentially relock all dependencies, e.g. while evolving your requirements. It will check that the lockfile is up-to-date and will never install anything that is not listed there.

As for the `--system` flag, you'd better drop it. There is no real harm on using a virtual environment inside docker images, but some subtle benefits. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064812/pipenv-system-option-for-docker-what-is-the-suggested-way-to-get-all-the-pyth#comment121422696_55065013) by @anishtain4. Pipenv now recommends against system-wide installs https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/pull/2762.